# Application Error while my Django app successfully deployed

Tags: django, heroku

I am leaving a question of why I got an application error after deploying Django successfully. It seems like I could deploy my Django app to Heroku, but I got an error when I wanted to see my app by pressing the "open app" button on the Heroku dashboard.
I am ignoring the database, which is Postgres, now. If I only care about the app without any data, I think I should be able to run the code on the Internet. Here is [my source code on github](https://github.com/mtake986/pfc_calc/tree/master), so I want you to check this out. Thanks so much in advance.

Here is the error message from Heroku.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: THanks for your comment